# ui library and ide for html/javascript/ajax to create desktop style app

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, jquery

I hope to develop a desktop app using html/javascript/ajax for the reason of multi platform.
Just wonder if there is an UI library and web IDE (likes webos enyo) for me to construct html/ajax app?

Welcome any comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use : http://www.sencha.com/, for example